# Facebook login from smart TV

Tags: facebook, samsung-smart-tv

Is is possible in facebook to open access for OAuth without opening an iframe. I need this to enable facebook login from my smart tv application.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. Unfortunately the Facebook App on Samsung SmartTVs is using a deprecated FB API no longer available for new 3rd party users.